# Why does reallocating with realloc, a pre-allocated memory using allocator::allocate conserve the old start memory address?

Tags: c++, malloc, realloc, allocator

The main problem was reallocating memory while expanding it and conserving data and the **first starting memory** address which is used by many other parts of the program (such as a static starting memory)

This doesn't work with realloc because he deallocate the precedent allocated memory and affects another with a new starting memory address:

```
 using namespace std;

 int *t = static_cast<int*>(malloc( 2*sizeof(int)));
   cout << "address " << t << endl;

 t = static_cast<int*>(realloc(t,10*sizeof(int)));
   cout << "address " << t << endl;

=========================

 // both of the addresses are different
 address 0x55c454fc5180
 address 0x55c454fc55b0
```

after testing many solutions (even direct access to the memory by system call), I found this one :

```
 allocator<int> alloc;
 int *t = alloc.allocate(2*sizeof(int));
   cout << "address " << t << endl;

 // reallocating memory using realloc
 t = static_cast<int*>(realloc(t, 10*sizeof(int)));
   cout << "address " << t << endl;

=========================
 
 // now the addresses are the same 
 address 0x55c454fc5180
 address 0x55c454fc5180
```

I tried to explain how it's possible but not able to match the both functioning and I want to know why and how it works.

Comment: It's like you have an acre of land, and you want two acres. If there is an acre for sale just next to yours, fine, consider yourself lucky. You buy it and you are done  But what if all the land around you is already taken? What do you do? You sell your parcel, buy a bigger one elsewhere, where there's land for sale, and move your stuff to the new place. So the answer to your question "how it works" is just that. You got lucky.

Answer (score 3):

Using `realloc` on an address allocated with `std::allocator`, `new` or anything similar has undefined behavior. It can only be used when the address comes from the `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` family of allocation functions. Never mix them.

In general `realloc` does not guarantee that the address of the allocation remains unchanged. There is no guarantee that `realloc` will be able to expand the allocation in place (e.g. there might not be enough memory free after the current allocation). It is the defined behavior of `realloc` to copy the memory block to a new allocation where sufficient space is free in such a situation. This also means that `realloc` can only be used with trivially-copyable types in C++.

If your program depends on the address of the allocation remaining unchanged, then it can't expand the allocation. You can have one of these, not both.

---

Also, you are using `std::allocator<int>` wrong. The argument to `.allocate` should be the number of elements of the array to allocate, not the number of bytes. Then afterwards you are supposed to call `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int>>::construct` or `std::construct_at` or a placement-new on each element of the array to construct and start the lifetime of the array elements.

I am not sure *why* you are trying to use `std::allocator` here, but it is unlikely that you need it. If you just intend to create an array of `int`, you should use `new int[n]`, not `std::allocator`. Or rather don't worry with manual memory management at all and just use `std::vector<int>`.